# What is a Scott Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

After seeing so many of these puzzles, I thought that it would be fun to try and make my own!

If a word conforms to a specific pattern, I call it a **Scott Word™**.  Use the words below to figure it out!

| Scott Words™ | not Scott Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| Golden | Silver |
| Pink | Magenta |
| Purple | Violet |
| Spring | Bounce |
| Possess | Take |
| Fox | Vixen |
| Bunny | Hare |
| Grizzly | Polar |
| Chicken | Duck |
| Baby | Child |
| Michael | Rachel |
| Mangle | Tangle |
| Toy | Plaything |
| Innards | Outwards |

Here's a csv version

```
Scott Words™,not Scott Words™
Golden,Silver
Pink,Magenta
Purple,Violet
Spring,Bounce
Possess,Take
Fox,Vixen
Bunny,Hare
Grizzly,Polar
Chicken,Duck
Baby,Child
Michael,Rachel
Mangle,Tangle
Toy,Plaything
Innards,Outwards
```

Please explain the pattern along with each line! Don't forget to explain the title as well!

Have fun!

Comment: Congrats on 2048 reputation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feels like a reach but most of the words do match.  Is it:

> Characters in Five Nights at Freddy's

Explanation:

> Golden = Golden Freddy
>  Pink = Pink Man
>  Purple = Purple Man
>  Spring = Springtrap
>  Possess = The Spirits
>  Fox = Foxy the Fox
>  Bunny = Bonnie the Bunny
>  Grizzly = Freddy Fazbear (not sure if he's a grizzly but definitely not a polar bear)
>  Chicken = Chica the Chicken
>  Baby = Circus Baby (Elizabeth)
>  Michael = The main character is Mike Schmidt
>  Mangle = The redesigned Foxy from Five Nights at Freddy's 2
>  Toy = The Toy Animatronics
>  Innards = Ennard (Molten Freddy)

And the title fits because

> The game was developed by Scott Cawthon